# R how to partial match vector with another n-length vectors

Tags: r, combinations

Please see the following table. I need to check whether Family includes any strings in the column of Appln_ID.

I plan to use

```
df$Match[grepl(paste(df$Appln_ID,collapse = "|"),df$Family)]<-"1"
```

but it doesn't work and reports "invalid regular expression CN02822097.8|CN200810105442.7|CN200680019886.8|C"

...

If I generate

```
set<-c(Appln_ID[1], Appln_ID[2]....Appln_ID[3000])
```

it works...I don't know why...

[image]

Comment: You want to check if `Appln_ID` is in *all* entries of `Family`? Or by matched row, that is, `Appln_ID[1]` in `Family[1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED for clarification from OP**

I made a fake data frame of the same format:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame( Appln_ID = letters[1:5],
              Family = sapply(1:5, function(x) paste0(letters[round(runif(runif(1)*10)*26)],collapse=";")))
```

Here's what it looks like:

```
  Appln_ID            Family
1        a               j;o
2        b e;w;y;q;p;b;e;e;r
3        c             t;m;s
4        d   j;t;x;f;q;c;g;j
5        e             w;i;m
```

To search which rows of `Family` can be found in all elements of `Appln_ID`, I use `tidyverse` and `iterators`:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("iterators")
library(tidyverse)
library(iterators)

search.all <- df %>%
                mutate(dummy = Family) %>%
                nest(dummy) %>%
                rowwise() %>%
                mutate(data = map(data, ~ unlist(strsplit(as.character(Family),";")))) %>%
                ungroup() %>%
                mutate(data = map(data, ~ (sum(sapply(iter(.x), function(y) y %in% Appln_ID) > 0)))) %>%
                unnest() %>%
                filter(data == 1) %>%
                select(-data)
```

The idea is to *1)* copy `Family` as a separate column (`dummy`), *2)* `strsplit` `dummy` and save as a nested list, *3)* determine whether any element of `dummy` is in `Appln_ID` and save as a logical, *4)* filter rows where conditional is `TRUE`.

The output:

```
  Appln_ID    Family
1        a m;e;v;q;u
2        d u;a;l;s;r
3        e   v;k;f;b
```

You forgot that `e` also contains a `b`.

Comment: Very thanks! I think the question is search all" Appln_ID" in all Family, based on your case, the expected result should be 
          Appln_ID            Family                                  
2        b                        e;w;y;q;p;b;e;e;r  (include b and e) 
4        d                         j;t;x;f;q;c;g;j         (include c)

Comment: Okay, so you want `Family` where an entry is in `Appln_ID`?